# Is ConversationTranscriber supported by the speech-to-text Docker container?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

ConversationTranscriber works great with the Azure speech service, however, when I run it agains the docker container it does not work.  The container logs show the following error.  I'm using the "latest" container tag.

Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/speech/recognition/multiaudio?language=en-us - - - 404

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

`ConversationTranscriber()` is having separate procedure to implement. Authentication is required to solve the error that occurred. Use the below pattern to check with the authentication and check with the implementation. The docker is not completely support the `ConversationTranscriber()` service.
`ConversationTranscriber()` is having language constraints. It works with .NET version only.

```
public sealed class ConversationTranscriber : Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Recognizer
```

`public string AuthorizationToken { get; set; }` -> Get the authentication token. Then it will be working with the URL generated.